# How do I get $index named variables to work in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I have a div on my html that is coded as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="loss in Model.plDetails track by $index">
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="loss.Date" id="loss-date{{$index+1}}"
               datepicker-pattern="((0[13578]|1[02])[-/]31[-/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((01|0[3-9]|1[1-2])[-/](29|30)[-/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-/](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[-/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((02)[-/]29[-/](((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000))"
               is-open="datePicker{{$index+1}}.opened" max="maxDate" max-date="maxDate" date-format placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,'datePicker{{$index+1}}')"><i class="icon icon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="number" ng-model="loss.amount" placeholder="$ Amount" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <select ng-model="loss.type" placeholder="Loss Type">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="2">Test</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    Add Line
</div>
</div>
```

The "open" function is coded in my javascript as:

```
$scope.open = function ($event, targetDatePicker) {
     $event.preventDefault();
     $event.stopPropagation();
     $scope[targetDatePicker].opened = !$scope[targetDatePicker].opened;
}
```

The problem is, when I try to run this code, I am first given an error that "Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 11 of the expression [datePicker{{$index+1}}.opened] starting at [{{$index+1}}.opened]."  This being on the line of code where the is-open is defined.

If I change the is-open to be datePicker1.opened, it works gets past the error (but won't work for my code in the long run as I need the last digit to be variable) but has another issue.  When clicking on the calendar icon to fire the ng-click event, an error of "Cannot read property 'opened' of undefined" is thrown because the "targetDatePicker" is interpreted as datePicker{{$index+1}} which doesn't exist.

There has to be a way to evaluate these values so they come out as datePicker1, datePicker2, etc...

Update:  I also tried the code at [This StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481587/how-to-use-index-to-set-angular-ui-bootstrap-calendar-is-open-attribute).  I tried setting up the code as:

```
            $scope.datePicker = {};
            $scope.open = function ($event, idx) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            $scope.datePicker['idx' + idx].opened = !$scope.datePicker['idx' + idx].opened;
        };
```

With HTML as `<input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-valid-date ng-touched" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="loss.Date" id="loss-date1" datepicker-pattern="((0[13578]|1[02])[-/]31[-/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((01|0[3-9]|1[1-2])[-/](29|30)[-/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-/](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[-/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((02)[-/]29[-/](((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000))" is-open="datePicker['idx'+$index].opened" max="maxDate" max-date="maxDate" date-format="" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">` but I still get the `Cannot read property 'opened' of undefined` error.

Comment: you shouldn't have to use curly braces in an ng-click attribute, try treating $index more like a javascript number ... 'datePicker' + ($index + 1)

Comment: In my second attempt, I removed datepicker altogether and just have `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,$index)"><i class="icon icon-calendar"></i></button>`,  Still get a `Cannot read property 'opened' of undefined error` error,

Comment: @SpaceCowboy74 are you expecting `datePicker{{$index+1}}` to be an object? How or where this object is initialized? Have you tried `is-open="datePicker[$index+1].opened"`?

Answer (score 1):

First error, you are missing a `}` in the `is-open` attribute, this will make angular not to parse it and just will be text, so

```
is-open="datePicker{{$index+1}.opened"
```

change it for

```
is-open="datePicker{{$index+1}}.opened"
```

Now, in your ng-click, you don't need the double `{{}}`, angularjs don't need to evaluate this to pass the string to the function, you just need something like this

```
ng-click="open($event,'datePicker'+($index+1))"
```

and this will do the magic.

I don't know how the datepicker you are using works, i'm just pointing the errors i see in your code. Hope it helps

**EDITED**
I've wrote an illustrative example, just for you to see the syntax and maybe you can find a piece of code that could help you with your issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>.:[Angularjs test]:.</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            'use strict';

            angular.module('kstr', []);
            angular
                .module('kstr')
                .controller('KstrController', KstrController);

            function KstrController(){
                var self = this;
                self.myList = ["kstro", "jhon", "jane"];
                self.datePicker = {};

                self.printit = function(index){
                    console.log(self.datePicker[index]);
                    self.datePicker[index].opened = !self.datePicker[index].opened;
                }
            }
        })();
      </script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="kstr">
    <div class="row" data-ng-controller="KstrController as kstr">
        <div data-ng-repeat="myItem in kstr.myList track by $index">
            <p>My item "{{myItem}}" with "datePicker{{$index+1}}"</p>
            <div data-ng-init="kstr.datePicker[$index+1]={opened:false}">
                <pre>var datePicker[{{$index+1}}].opened = {{kstr.datePicker[$index+1].opened}}</pre>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" data-ng-click="kstr.printit($index+1)">Change it</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my copy paste.  I had the extra curly brace in the original code.  It's what gave the "Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 11 of the expression [datePicker{{$index+1}}.opened] starting at [{{$index+1}}.opened]."  error.

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I resolved it.  I ended up moving the opened to my object the details were bound to.  This is passed in with the open function and all seems to work now.

```
        $scope.Model.plDetails = [{ date: "", amount: "", opened: false, type: 1 }];
        $scope.open= function ($event, loss) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            loss.opened = !loss.opened;
        };
        $scope.addLossItem = function () {
            $scope.Model.plDetails.push({ date: "", amount: "", opened: false, type: 1 });
        };
        $scope.removeLossItemAt = function (itemToRemove) {
            if ($scope.Model.plDetails.length === 1)
                return;
            $scope.Model.plDetails.splice($scope.Model.plDetails.indexOf(itemToRemove), 1);
        };
```

My html was set up as:

```
       <div class="row" ng-if="Model.ApplicantLosses==0">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h4>Prior Loss Details</h4>
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <div ng-repeat="loss in Model.plDetails track by $index" style="margin-top: 10px">
                                <div class="col-sm-1" style="width: 2%; margin-top: inherit;">
                                    <label id="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="loss.Date" id="loss-date{{$index+1}}"
                                               datepicker-pattern="((0[13578]|1[02])[-/]31[-/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((01|0[3-9]|1[1-2])[-/](29|30)[-/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-/](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[-/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((02)[-/]29[-/](((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000))"
                                               is-open="loss.opened" max="maxDate" max-date="maxDate" date-format placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" />
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,loss)"><i class="icon icon-calendar"></i></button>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-9">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="display: inline-table">
                                        <input type="number" ng-model="loss.amount" placeholder="$ Amount" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="display: inline-table">
                                        <select id="loss-type{{$index+1}}" ng-model="loss.type" ng-options="lossType.idng-show as lossType.name for lossType in lossTypeParameters" class="form-control" required>
                                            <option value="" disabled>Loss Type</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="display: inline-table">
                                        <span><a id="loss-del-item{{$index+1}}" ng-show="Model.plDetails.length > 1" style="vertical-align: middle" ng-click="removeLossItemAt(loss)"><i class="icon icon-minus-square-o icon-lg"></i>&nbsp;Remove Line</a></span>
                                        <span ng-show="Model.plDetails.length != 2 && $index+1 == Model.plDetails.length"><a id="loss-add-item{{$index+1}}" ng-click="addLossItem()"><i class="icon icon-plus-square-o icon-lg"></i>&nbsp;Add Line</a></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```